# UISearchBar textfield not editable after back from details view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

UISearchBar textfield not editable after back from details view, but the select option can be visible also cross button working.  [image]

Using the following code,

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
- (void)showKeyboard {
    [self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Which is working first time but when back it's not working. But the breakpoint on showKeyboard method is working.

This search is used in two different section and code is like this -

```
UINavigationController *navController =self.navigationController;
    TPTabBarController *tabbar = nil;

    if([navController.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[TPTabBarController class]]){
        tabbar = (TPTabBarController *)navController.presentingViewController;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Failed to get tabbar in TPBookViewController. It is nil.");
    }

    if(tabbar != nil && tabbar.searchNavigationController != nil){
        if(tabbar.searchNavigationController.viewControllers.count == 2){
            //current view is SearchResultViewController
            SearchResultViewController *searchResultViewController = (SearchResultViewController*)tabbar.searchNavigationController.viewControllers[1];
            [searchResultViewController reloadDataAndLocateToPage:self.currentPage manual:_currentManual];
        }
        [self presentViewController:tabbar.searchNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

In one section is working but in another view controller it's not working

Comment: Try viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear

Comment: @Rajesh it's not working